# CKfinder - upload img into text editor

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am sorry for bothering you but I would like to ask if anybody of you had a similar problem with implementation CKfinder on the server.
On my localhost the CKeditor with CKfinder for upload imgs working well but when I build my react project and upload it into the server where I want to run the website - there I am getting the error during upload imgs saying (Invalid request - error 400).
[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOhM3.jpg)

I would be gratefull for anything because can not find out what´s exactly wrong.

Thanks a lot and wish you a great day :)

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting and check the server logs